# Automatically macro run if system time every 10 minutes between start time to end time VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on Excel 2013,
I need the automatic macro run if system time every 10 minutes between start time to end time VBA excel.

```
VBA Code:
'In Workbook events:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Update
End Sub

'In a Module:
Dim RunTimer As Date
Sub Update()
   RunTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
   Application.OnTime RunTimer, "Update"

  'Do Something Your Code
   MsgBox "Data Update.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

eg:

1. Excel Open
2. start time is 9:30 AM
3. end time is 5:00 PM
4. show the "msgbox" every 10 minutes

Kindly help me, thanks in advance

I need the automatic macro run if system time every 10 minutes between start time to end time VBA excel

Answer (score 2):

Let your code run *any* time as it already does. Your current code issues the call every 20s, as you need it only every 10m, change the assignment to `RunTimer` to `TimeValue("00:10:00")`.

Now the code will run all 10 minutes. All you need is to check if the current time is between 9:30 and 17:00. If yes, execute what ever you want.

```
Sub Update()
    Const StartTime = "09:30"
    Const EndTime = "17:00"
    
    Dim RunTimer As Date
    RunTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
    Application.OnTime RunTimer, "Update"

    If Time >= CDate(StartTime) And Time <= CDate(EndTime) Then
        'Do whatever you need to...
        MsgBox "Data Update.", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where was this before I started fiddling with Windows' Taskplanner for my daily updates :') Ah well, knowledge acquired. Would it not be better to have an `Else` clause to trigger the procedure back at 9:30 rather than it continuing in the evening/night (whilst not doing anything besides making a new planned task)? Maybe doesn't matter, shouldn't take up any significant process power.

Comment: If you don't issue a new `OnTime`, the procedure will never be called again once it is past 5pm - you would initiate the process manually by somehow calling the `Update` function. Don't worry about processing time - you will never notice it.

Comment: I was more talking about an `If...Else` adjustment to the Runtimer to the next morning if the `Time > CDate(EndTime)` but thanks for clarifying that my worry is indeed for naught.

Comment: Yes!!! It's Work me above code, thank You so much Mr.FunThomas